# WebApi Controller create action method works fine on the front end application, but on the unit test Request is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller action

```
// POST api/TiposDeCanal   add
        public HttpResponseMessage PostTipoDeCanal(TipoDeCanal tipoDeCanal)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                unitOfWork.TipoDeCanalRepository.Insert(tipoDeCanal);
                unitOfWork.Save();

                DataSourceResult result = new DataSourceResult
                {
                    Data = new[] { tipoDeCanal },
                    Total = 1
                };
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, result);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = tipoDeCanal.ID}));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }
```

My view is using telerik controls and works perfectly fine

```
@model List<PowerData.Comisiones.Models.TipoDeCanal>
@using PowerData.Comisiones.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tipos de Canal";
}

<h2>Tipos de Canal</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TipoDeCanal>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Nombre).Title("Nombre");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Descripcion).Title("Descripcion");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())   
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
    .Filterable()  
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .WebApi()
        //.Ajax()
        //.ServerOperation(false)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
            model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(false);
        })
        .Create(create => create.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TipoDeCanales" }))) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
            .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TipoDeCanales" }))) // Action invoked when the grid needs data
            .Update(update => update.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TipoDeCanales", id = "{0}" })))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TipoDeCanales", id = "{0}" }))) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item

        //.Create(update => update.Action("Create", "TipoDeCanales"))
        //.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "TipoDeCanales"))
        //.Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "TipoDeCanales"))
        //.Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "TipoDeCanales"))
    )
)
<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            toastr.error(message)
            //alert(message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The above code works perfectly fine on the browser, however the  unit test fails on the line Request.CreateResponse because the request object is null.

```
[TestClass]
    public class TipoDeCanalesControllerTest: GenericApiController
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void PostTipoDeCanal()
        {
            TipoDeCanalesController TipoDeCanal = new TipoDeCanalesController();
            Assert.Equals(TipoDeCanal.PostTipoDeCanal(new Models.TipoDeCanal { Descripcion = "Unit Test Description", Nombre = "Test" }).StatusCode,
                System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use mock to fake httprequest, you have none in your unit test, in the browser it works because browse to your url,an httprequest is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need anything from `Request` you can satisfy the instance like this:

```
TipoDeCanalesController TipoDeCanal = new TipoDeCanalesController();

TipoDeCanal.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
TipoDeCanal.Request.SetConfiguration(new HttpConfiguration());

Assert.Equals(TipoDeCanal.PostTipoDeCanal(new Models.TipoDeCanal { Descripcion = "Unit Test Description", Nombre = "Test" }).StatusCode,
                System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created);
```